# Is it possible to solve sextic equations using the Fox H function?

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, galois-theory, algebraic-equations

Although the [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function) can solve the sextic equation, the details about it are shrouded in the fog of more than a century ago.

In contrast, we know more about the [Fox H function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function), and we have even succeeded in implementing it on CAS.

I would like to know if the experts of the Fox H function have a more modern understanding of the solution of the sextic equation.

Answer (score 7):

*Trinomial* sextic equations $z^6-z-t=0$ can be solved in terms of the Fox H function:

$$z_j=\tfrac{1}{5}t H_{2,3}^{1,2}\biggl(te^{j\frac{2 i \pi }{5}}\biggl|
\begin{array}{c}
(0,1),(0,6/5)  \\
 (0,1),(-1,1),(0,1/5) \\
\end{array}
\biggr)+e^{-j\frac{2 i \pi }{5}},\;\;j\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$$

<sub>Mathematica input:</sub>

```
(t/5)*FoxH[{{{0,1},{0,6/5}},{}},{{{0,1}},{{-1,1},{0,1/5}}},t Exp[(2 Pi I)/5]^j]+Exp[(2 Pi I)/5]^-j
```

This is a special case of a more general solution of trinomial equations of arbitrary order, $z^\alpha-\beta z+\gamma=0$, described in [*All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3) (J. Math. Chem. **57** (2019) pp 59–106).

Comment: That's pretty good, but I must remind the reader that the sextic equations can only be reduced to 2-parameter sextic equation $x^6 + a x^2 + b x + b = 0$ by the usual method...

Comment: In fact any trinomial sextic having this form $z^6-\beta z^m+\gamma=0$, for $m\in\{0,1,..,5\}$ can be put in terms of Fox-Wright $_2\Psi_1$ function that is a special case of FoxH. For $m$ integer it can be also set in terms of a series of  generalized hypergeometric functions.